# Input string was not in a correct format. error occurs only on one server

Tags: c#, string

I have a weird error, it occurs only in one server, when i run locally or on another server its runs successfully,
I am calling a simple function like below

```
List<string> waste_List = new List<string>();
```

"waste_List " is a list , Rest all parameters are of "string" type.

```
 manualTransaction_count = manualReductionDataextract.func_ManualReductionTransaction(manualReduction_list, storeNumFromLogFile, v_StoreUserId,
                                    manualTempFile, logFileName);
```

function definition is as below :

```
public int func_ManualReductionTransaction(List<string> manualReduction_list, string v_StoreNumber, string v_StoreUserId,
      string manualTempFile, string logFileName)
    {.... //body }
```

**i am getting error as below:**

> Input string was not in a correct format. lineNumber:25278 Stack
>   Trace:   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles
>   options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)    at System.Double.Parse(String s) 
>   at
>   FileParser.ManualReductionTransaction.func_ManualReductionTransaction(List`1
>   manualReduction_list, String v_StoreNumber, String v_StoreUserId,
>   String manualTempFile, String logFileName)

**Server OS: MS windows 2003 server R2**
**Has net 4.0 installed**

Please suggest

Comment: Could be the default culture on your server. If it was set to Dutch and you sent over a string with multiple commas as groupings (traditional english format) then a failure would occur because in Dutch it has the opposite meaning. If you do not specify a culture in your `parse` method then the thread culture is used. The thread culture is the default culture used by the application which defaults to the servers default locale. So it is critical that you specify a culture at some point in that stack, otherwise who knows what will happen.

Comment: You need to flesh your question out more.  The question needs the full method, not just it's signature.  We need to see which line is causing the error.

Comment: As @Igor said, it seems a Culture problem. you need to change the `Double.Parse` method you are using for the overload that accepts a IFormatProvider [Double.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Igor, I have another function which passes same parameters but different List , that function works

Comment: Your stack trace very clearly points to `System.Number.ParseDouble` as the point at which the exception is thrown. That happens for 2 reasons: 1) The string is not a valid number and 2) the format of that number does not allign with the culture/IFormat provider passed in or if none is passed in the culture on the executing thread which defaults to the default culture of the application which defaults to the default culture of the windows user context. That is as good of an answer as you are going to get, go on it and you will figure it out.

Comment: If you want more help then provide the following: 1) The exact value of the string that causes the error. 2) The full method call and values of the parameters passed to `System.Number.ParseDouble` 3) The culture of the current thread if that is not passed to the code. Without those things no one else (here) can help you any further.

Comment: As @Igor says - without an actual code listing, you're on your own.  What ever string is being passed to Double.Parse is not a valid double.  Ideally we need the code for the method (with line numbers) and the data you are sending in when the error occurs.